# chage php code to work on button click instead of page load

Tags: php

i am trying to change my php code to work on button click instead on page load ?

when page load this my code below run instead of on click ?

here's my code i have tried and i am trying to make it to work on click with a button instead of page load.

```
<?php

$myFile = "filename2.php";   
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w'); // or die("error");  
$stringData = "Hello";   
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

?>
```

this code is for creating pages. now this code works to create aa page but i want it to work when a button clicked

EDIT #2 Code

sorry i am still learning but here on my code i tried to specify the folder where my php code going to create a page in it

here's my code

```
    <form method="post">
    <input type='text' name='filename' placeholder='Enter a filename'>
    <input type='submit' value='Run the Script'>
    <option>
    <select value="Folder1" name="thisfolder">Folder1</select>
    <select value="Folder2" name="thisfolder">Folder2</select>
    <select value="Folder3" name="thisfolder">Folder3</select>
    </option>
    </form>

<?php
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
  { 
  $filename=$_POST['filename']; $myFile = .$thisfolder. "/page" .$filename.".php";
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
  $stringData = "Hello";
  fwrite($fh, $stringData); } 
?>
```

wanted to make it like, from option box i must select folder where i want page.php

i didn't know how to make it work. hope it's clear

Comment: PHP runs on the server. It doesn't exist in the browser, therefore it can't be run `onclick`.

Comment: m point is. my code is for creating pages. now when i place that code on my page it will create a page wen i open the page that contains this code. instead of that i want to make a button and each time that button clicked it runs this code to create that page

Comment: test my code you understand what i mean

Comment: Then that code should be in its own file ("file2.php", with additional code to redirect to the first page after it has completed `header('Location: **your page**');`  Then, in the first page, you need to have the button direct them to file2.php

Comment: Why would you even want to do this?

Comment: @JustinTaddei dear because i have somethng in mind that works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create 2 files.

Use this codes instead. This will run your code on click.

```
    <html>
    <form method="post">
    <input type='submit' value='Run the Script'>
    </form>
    </html>
   <?php 
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
    {
       $myFile = "filename2.php";   
       $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w'); // or die("error");  
       $stringData = "Hello";   
       fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: dear, what if i want to make a text box to put file name to be created instead of i write file name in the code ? without page extention just the name. and page extention like `php` should be in the code

Comment: <html>
    <form method="post">
   <input type='text' name='filename' placeholder='Enter a filename'>
    <input type='submit' value='Run the Script'>
    </form>
    </html>
   <?php 
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
    {
       $filename=$_POST['filename'];
       $myFile = $filename.".php";
       $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w'); // or die("error");  
       $stringData = "Hello";   
       fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    }
   ?>

Comment: dear i have edited my question and add #2 code can you please check it out. for some reason i am not able to post a question

Comment: Change your select tag. Read more about them from here : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

And also put the submit tag below the select tag and name the select tag as filename

Comment: what aboutmy php code i made is it right ? i ddon't think i made it currectly

Comment: Change it to the following:
$myFile = $thisfolder. "/page" .$filename.".php";
The dot before $thisfolder is creating problems.

Comment: but i get error on `Warning: fopen(/pagemyfolder.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\page1.php on line 26`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136931/discussion-between-resheil-agarwal-and-mm-pp).

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

Put this code inside `create_page.php`

```
<?php
$myFile = "filename2.php";   
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w'); // or die("error");  
$stringData = "Hello";   
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

?>
```

Put this code inside inside `index.php`

```
<a href="create_page.php">Craete Page</a>
```